# Who is the boy who gives Superman of other Earth his suit?

Tags: dc, character-identification, justice-society-world-war-ii

In the animated movie *Justice Society: World War II*, there is a boy who gives Superman of other Earth his suit, and said that someone said to give it to him. Who is the boy, and who gave the suit to him?

[image]

Comment: As far as I can tell, the character is a random. They're not credited as a [voice actor](https://www.behindthevoiceactors.com/movies/Justice-Society-World-War-II/Prisoner/), nor do they receive an IMDB credit. Probably it was just one of the main cast doing the voice as an "*additional voices*".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It was almost certainly Dr. Fate who gave the package to the boy. This is strongly hinted at by something he says in a later scene:

> Dr. Fate: No! He's not ready yet! Yes, he's received the package, but he doesn't know what it means!

It was implied that Dr. Fate knew certain things about the future...

> ... for example, he told Hawkman that he'd "see her again soon" (likely referring to Hawkgirl, who apparently died a long time ago in this movie),  seemingly predicting the fact that Hawkman would later be killed by the Atlanteans.

He also muttered the following (seemingly to himself, though he was probably talking to [Nabu](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Nabu))...

> Dr. Fate: Should we tell them? Yes, yes. They should know. They should know.

> Dr. Fate: Dead. They're all going to be dead. They need to know. They should know.

... implying that he knew about some impending catastrophe, possibly involving the demise of everyone in the JSA.

> This event did not occur in the movie, so it may be something that will come to pass in a sequel.

And we saw that Dr. Fate was at least partially responsible for the Barry Allen Flash  arriving on Earth-One, so it definitely seemed like he was orchestrating events to ensure that all the heroes would be where they were required at the appropriate time, almost like a Chess master moving pieces around a board.

As for the identity of the boy in your image, that's much harder to determine. There is at least a possibility that he's a new character created for the movie, rather than one adapted from the comics. However, he did say something (which I've bolded in the quote below) implying that there may be more to his story, which could be expanded upon in a sequel:

> Unnamed Boy: It's you. He said you would come... and here you are. This is yours. I'm supposed to give this to you.
>
> Clark Kent: What are you talking about, kid?
>
> Unnamed Boy: Take it. Use it. **You have to make sure it never happens. I'm sure that's why I'm back here now.** He said you'd know what to do.
>
> Clark Kent: *Who* said?!

This dialogue is very much open to interpretation, but it implies that he may be from the future, perhaps from the time of the impending catastrophe hinted at by Dr. Fate. It's impossible to say with certainty though, because, aside from his appearance, the movie doesn't offer any more clues as to who he is, and the character isn't listed in any credits that I've been able to find. It's also a little too soon after the movie's release to expect any Word of God clarification on this.

I've seen some speculation that he could be [Kamandi, the Last Boy on Earth](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Kamandi_(Earth-AD)). Again, there's no way to be sure of that, but there is a vague physical resemblance, and it would fit with him being sent back from a post-apocalyptic future, if that is indeed what happened. That said, I'm not aware of Kamandi ever interacting with Superman or the JSA in the comics.

Comment: Kamandi never met Superman as far as I know, but in an issue of his comic in 1975, he came upon a cult of apes that worshiped the legend of Superman as a holy mythos. Their focus of worship was Superman's suit that had survived the catastrophe.

Comment: There was a Kamandi short film that played before the Justice Society film

Comment: That could tie in with those apes worshipping Superman's costume in the future, mentioned in Bjorn Eriksson's comment. Perhaps that's the very same costume the boy handed to Clark. (Albeit, that would create a bootstrap paradox, since the costume would then be circling around in a time loop with no clear point of origin.)